# Jackson JSON deserializing wrapper objects

Tags: java, json, apache-beam, auto-value

I am reading a REST-API, which returns a result in the following fashion

```json
{
  "total": 2,
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "object-name",
      "id": 123
    },
    {
      "name": "another-object-name",
      "id": 321
    }
  ]
}
```

In addition to the properties `name` and `id`, elements of `results` also include other properties, depending on object type. All objects in `results` are of the same type. There is no property which indicates what object type the element is.

I am working with Apache Beam, and am using `AutoValue` together with JacksonJson to parse these objects. For example, the object `Circle` look like this:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AutoValue_Circle.Builder.class)
@AutoValue
public abstract class Circle implements Serializable {

  public static Circle.Builder builder() {
    return Circle.Builder.builder();
  }

  @JsonProperty("name")
  public abstract String name();

  @JsonProperty("id")
  public abstract int id();

  @JsonProperty("radius")
  public abstract double radius();

  @JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build")
  @AutoValue.Builder
  public abstract static class Builder {

    @JsonCreator
    public static Builder builder() {
      return new AutoValue_Circle.Builder();
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    abstract Builder name(String name);

    @JsonProperty("id")
    abstract Builder id(int id);

    @JsonProperty("radius")
    abstract Builder radius(double radius);

    abstract Circle build();
  }
}
```

I know what type is contained in `results`. For example making a GET request from `/api/circles` will return a list of circles.

I am using Apache beam pipelines to handle this:

```java
// jsonData is a PCollection<String>, which holds JSONs
PCollection<ApiWrapperObj> data = jsonData.apply(ParseJsons.of(ApiWrapperObj.class).setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(ApiWrapperObj.class));
```

So I need to make a deserializer for the wrapper object. Is there a way for me to use a Generic Class for example?